# Computing the optimal number of items per page such that a given range of items are displayed on a single page, of lowest index

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of items, numbered 1 to n, which I am displaying on several pages. If I display `page_size` items per page, I will have `ceiling(n/page_size)` pages in the end.

My question is : given a range of items `x to y`, how can I optimize my number of items per page (i.e `page_size`) such that (by priority) :

1. that range is displayed on a single page
2. the number of items per page is as small as possible.
3. the index of the page that contains that range is as small as possible

For example, for items `1 to 10`, a `page_size` of 10 is the best : all the items are displayed on page 1. For items `21 to 40`, a `page_size` of 20 is optimal, and you have all the items on page 2.

Any ideas on how to compute the best number of items per page ?

Comment: I think you mean you want the smallest value of `page_size`, and `page` can be whatever. If `page_size` is unrestricted I can just set `page_size=y, page=1`.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't very consistent in the words that I used. By "page" I mean range of items that gets retrieved, not page_number. I'll clarify this in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple solution, hopefully it's enough:

```
from math import ceil

def range_fits_in_page(x, y, page_size):
    page_num = int(ceil(x * 1.0 / page_size))
    page_start = (page_num - 1) * page_size + 1
    assert page_start <= x
    page_end = page_start + page_size - 1
    print("Trying page of size %(page_size)s at page number %(page_num)s "
          "ranging from %(page_start)s to %(page_end)s"
          % locals())
    return page_end >= y

def find_smallest_page(x, y):
    size = y - x + 1
    while not range_fits_in_page(x, y, size):
        size += 1
    return size

print find_smallest_page(20, 35)
```

Output:

```
Trying page of size 16 at page number 2 ranging from 17 to 32
Trying page of size 17 at page number 2 ranging from 18 to 34
Trying page of size 18 at page number 2 ranging from 19 to 36
18
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is as follows :

> Compute the number of items
>
> > range_size <-- 1+y-x
>
> We initialize the number of items per page to that number
>
> > page_size <-- range_size
>
> Compute the modulus of the first item of the range by that number
>
> > mod <-- x-1 % page_size
>
> We now increment the number of items per page until they all fit on one page :
>
> > While (mod + range_size > page_size)
> >
> > > page_size <-- page_size + 1
> > >
> > > mod <-- x-1 % page_size
>
> Return page_size

**Example of execution :**

For the range 15 to 19 :

range_size = 5

Loop 1 : page_size = 5, mod = 4, 4+5 > 5 so we increment page_size

Loop 2 : page_size = 6, mod = 2, 2+5 > 6 so we increment page_size

Loop 3 : page_size = 7, mod = 0, 0+5 > 7 is not true so we're done

In the end, with page_size 7, the range 15 to 19 is displayed on page 3, with 2 additional items (we have items 15 to 21).

I have not analyzed the running time.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but some thoughts that are too long for a comment :) .  Given 1-based indexing and integer `div` that discards remainder, you want the smallest `page_size` that satisfies conditions similar to the following:

```
x mod page_size < y mod page_size    (x comes before y on the page)
x div page_size == y div page_size   (they fall on the same page)
```

Those conditions can be expressed as equations by breaking down [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) into its implementation, e.g., `i mod j = i - j*floor(i/j)`.  Given `x` and `y`, those equations can be solved for `page_size`.